# Grafana 8 - reduced alert on multiple queries

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

In Grafana 8, there's a possibility to reduce the query and alert on each of the series separately: [image: Screenshot 1]

Resulting in such alert:
[image: Screenshot 2]

However, in real circumstances, I have 4 different metrics to monitor:
[image: Screenshot 3]

Currently, I have 4 alert rules with 1 query each. Is there a way to, having just one alert rule with multiple queries, receive a state of each series (i.e. per instance)?

Thanks in advance.